# two dimensional array with 3 characters per entry?

Tags: string, array

my plan is to create a two dimensional array with 3 characters in each cell.

what i have tried:

```
char keys[3][8][8] = {
  {' ','4','5','6','x','/',' ',' '},
  {'x10','7','8','9',' ',' ',' ',' '},
  {'.','rcl','eng','(',')','sd','m+','^2'},
  {'0','(-)','..,,','hyp','sin','cos','tan','hyp'},
  {' ','br','wur','^2','^x','log','ln',' '},
  {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','mode','log',' '},
  {'=',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','^3',' '},
  {'=','1','2','3','+','-',' ',' '}
};
```

unfortunatelly this gives me the error:

> error: too many initializers for 'char [3][8][8]'

so what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> error: too many initializers for 'char [3][8][8]'

The order is wrong:

```
char keys[8][8][3]
```

But then some of the literals are larger than int and give a warning as they are truncated.

Easiest is to define as string literals:

```
const char* keys[8][8] = {
  {" ","4","5","6","x","/"," "," "},
  {"x10","7","8","9"," "," "," "," "},
  {".","rcl","eng","(",")","sd","m+","^2"},
  {"0","(-)","..,,","hyp","sin","cos","tan","hyp"},
  {" ","br","wur","^2","^x","log","ln"," "},
  {" "," "," "," "," ","mode","log"," "},
  {"="," "," "," "," "," ","^3"," "},
  {"=","1","2","3","+","-"," "," "}
};
```

This can be further improved (stored in program memory, etc).

Cheers!